# Why won't the body formatting work?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems getting the background formatting to work with my  and  tags. The text I type is showing up and formatting like I want, but I want the white background and border to extend down too. I've tried a couple things, including doing away with the #bodywrapper and extending the #headerwrapper by adding a height. I'd rather not do this, but I guess I will if I have to. If I add a paragraph within the #bodywrapper, but outside of the section or aside tags, it works correctly. Why isn't this working?

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
#headerwrapper {
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:.5em;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-bottom:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  border-top-left-radius:.625em;
  border-top-right-radius:.625em;
  border:1px #000000 solid;}

.header {
  width:100%;
  height:10em;
  margin:0;
  border-bottom:3px #4E5E78 solid;}

img {
  float:left;
  margin-top:1.5em;
  margin-right:1em;
  margin-bottom:1.4em;
  margin-left:1em;}

#bodywrapper {
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:0em;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-bottom:2em;
  margin-left:auto;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-left-radius:.625em;
  border-bottom-right-radius:.625em;
  border:1px #000000 solid;}

section {
  width:60%;
  float:left;
  margin:auto;}

aside {
  width:40%;
  float:right;
  margin:auto;}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="headerwrapper">
<div class="header">
<img src="images/headerlogo.png" alt="Digital Billboard Guru" />
<h1>Call Now For Your<br />FREE Consultation<br />(000)000-0000</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bodywrapper">
<section>
<p>Test</p>
</section>
<aside>
<p>Test</p>
</aside>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:auto` to the `#bodywrapper`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/QLeN5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` into the tags so that u don't have to adding the height.

I hope this is what you want.